# Photoshop gets stuck in one tool and wont accept keyboard shortcut while painting

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

So I'm painting with the brush tool, and I mess up and hit <kbd>E</kbd> on my keyboard for the eraser but the tool doesn't change. I hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> and nothing happens, I hit <kbd>M</kbd> for marqee nothing happens.

But.

When I click my mouse in the gray area thats part of the window plane like layers/tools etc, I am able to use my keyboard shortcuts again.

Its as though photoshop didn't recognize that I had stopped using the brush tool and kept me locked in until I clicked on something that is not part of the canvas to "wake it up".

I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that "issue" too, even though it's not an issue.

The explanation is that due to your shortcut combo, you end up pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> key which takes focus to the upper menu tab ( file, edit and so on, you can see them selected ). You need to place focus on you drawing board again by either clicking on it or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> again.

This loss of focus also happens when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change between windows.

You'll get used to it.

Comment: I see. I can adjust to that I guess. Thanks for clarifying it for me.

Comment: @KaranveerSingh Glad I could help ;) It's annoying sometimes, especially when you are changing between languages when designing and this happens.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a wacom that might be the problem. 
check this link out. it should work.

https://fstoppers.com/bts/photoshop-shortcuts-stop-working-when-using-wacom-tablets-solution-55592

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.